# Python erro- "too many values to unpack using numpy.loadtxt" large data file

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy.loadtxt to read in dates from a csv file. I am getting the error that there are too many values to unpack. This is likely true in the literal sense because there are over 46,000 rows of dates. I would like to know if there is a way to read in the data without further breaking up the file. It has been broken up from one large zip file into site locations which I would like to keep together. The code is as follows:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates  as mdates

def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), dialect='excel')
    return [result[column] for result in results]

time = getColumn("C:\Users\dfmcg\Documents\Thesis     files\ALL_GPMP_O3_Met\ASIS-MA.csv",1)
for i in range (0,len(time)):
    x=time[i]
    x=x[0:(len(x)-3)]
    time[i]=x
print time[0:10]

time = time[1:]
from datetime import date

NewData = np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str, unpack=True,
    converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')})

print (NewData)

print NewData.shape()

date, ozone = NewData
```

Error is as follows:

```
c:\users\dfmcg\appdata\local\temp\tmpkbgiq_.py in <module>()
     19 #time = [date.datetime.strptime(item,"%Y/%m/%d"), float(time) for item in data
     20 date, ozone = np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str, unpack=True,
```

---> 21 converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')})

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here is  one row of data:

```
ABBR    DATE              O3    SWS VWS SWD VWD SDWD    TMP RH  RNF SOL
ASIS-MA 06/01/2005 00   -999    -999                    -999   -999 -999
```

Comment: please post the actual error text, it will be helpful in diagnosing the problem. `too many value to unpack` actually generally means you tried to expand a tuple/list into components and it failed because there weren't enough elements. My instinct tells me it's the `date, ozone` line, it's not expanding the return from `np.loadtxt` the way you think it is (there are more than two columns), but without the error text can't say for sure. A sample of the data you're trying to load would be helpful as well.

Comment: c:\users\dfmcg\appdata\local\temp\tmpkbgiq_.py in <module>()
     19 #time = [date.datetime.strptime(item,"%Y/%m/%d"), float(time) for item in data
     20 date, ozone = np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str, unpack=True,
---> 21     converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')})

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: I have added the error, it indicates that the error is in the converter line

Comment: Please update the original post with the details via an edit so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: ABBR DATE O3 SWS VWS SWD VWD SDWD TMP RH RNF SOL
ASIS-MA 06/01/2005 00 -999 -999  -999  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999
ASIS-MA 06/01/2005 01 -999 -999  -999  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999

Comment: I have put the data in the same format that is in the csv file--%m/%d/%Y. I had that error already and fixed it. Unless this is not what you mean.

Comment: What is data row, not the title of the csv?

Comment: the data row that is visible is all -999. The real data doesn't show up until around line 800.

Comment: Why are you using `unpack=True` with only one LHS variable?

Comment: It is fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
date, ozone = np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str, unpack=True,
    converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')})
```

Try using this:

```
NewData = np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str, unpack=True,
    converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')})
```

or try since the error is in the converter

```
 NewData = np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str )

#to view array 
print NewData.shape

#Then:
date, ozone = NewData
```

When you know the shape then, build your tuple.

Comment: I receive the error that the 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: print NewData.shape()

Comment: I have tried with he NewData = np.loadtxt you suggested which is when I received the error. I tried just printing NewData and got the same error that the tuple was not callable

Comment: When I print New data some of the dates are being read as dates and some as a number like so:

Comment: ['D', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005', '06/01/2005']
['732098.0' '732098.0' '732098.0' ..., '734050.0' '734050.0' '734050.0']

Comment: Well the problem is that the first couple are not being changed from dates to numbers. I am not sure How to fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: it look like you have 12 columns with date being the 2 column. Look at numpy slicing to get the data you want out NewData. Do this before fixing  any other data problems.

Comment: I have already taken out all of the other columns, it is now only looking at my date column. My problem now is that: date, ozone = NewData, gives the error that there are too many values to unpack. Could this now be because the file is large?

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. I am not referencing ozone, I separated them to figure out what was wrong with time. I received the shape and it seems to be working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The error (probably) means that `np.loadtxt` is returning more than two variables.

You would get the same error with

```
a,b = (1,2,3)
```

My suggestion: try

```
print(np.loadtxt(time, delimiter=',',dtype=str, unpack=True,converters = {0: mdates.strpdate2num('%m/%d/%Y')}))
```

is it returning only 2 values like you expect?

Comment: i can't print it because it is not getting past the line due to the error

Comment: I was expecting the date which should be more than 2 values